# Which "diagnostics.wadcfg" is used?

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I am learning to configure diagnostics in microsoft azure. In order to configure the diagnostics we can use visual studio as suggested in this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn186185.aspx) article. And whatever changes we do all gets saved to the "diagnostics.wadcfg" file present under role in the cloud project.

We can also add our own "diagnostics.wadcfg" file to the root folder of our worker role also. And add configuration setting to it. As suggested in these articles [[1]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidhardin/archive/2011/03/29/configuring-wad-via-the-diagnostics-wadcfg-config-file.aspx) and [[2]](http://blog.elastacloud.com/2011/02/13/file-based-diagnostics-config-with-intellisense-in-azure-sdk-1-3/).

[image]

Can somebody tell me whats the difference between "diagnostics.wadcfg" files present in both the places and there precedence.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question!!! Just out of curiosity, I tried it and here's what I found: Essentially if you have diagnostics.wadcfg file in both places, the file in project root folder is ignored and the diagnostics.wadcfg file under your role is used. In fact, I don't think you can even delete this file without modifying the build targets as this file is copied as part of your build process.

Here's another interesting article that you may find useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn205146.aspx.

Comment: Thanks. I also had the same thought, that the config associated with role, will override the one we have at the root level. But was confused why is it there, as config in the role, won't get deleted also. Is the config in the root approach an older one, and with the new template the config gets associated with the role itself ? Thanks for the link i have already gone through it, but they have not said a word regarding the presence of config in the root, so landed over here.  +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Gaurav's answer is correct for the specific question asked and I have upvoted it.  But I wanted to add some additional information that may help guide your decision.  You are configuring Windows Azure Diagnostics (WAD) 1.0 which has been around since Azure started.  There is a new version - WAD 1.2 - that is now available and allows you to setup and configure diagnostics after deploying your service.  This new version of WAD provides more control, features, and easier configuration settings.  Visual Studio will provide a UI for WAD 1.2 in the next 1 or 2 Azure SDK releases, but in the meantime you can use the information at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/ to use WAD 1.2.

Comment: Thanks for the link i have already explored it. And i am very much aware of the new WAD 1.2 version, but i wanted to start with WAD 1.0 and then come to 1.2. +1 :)